# Android sdkmanager - unable to run the SDK manager

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to run the Android SDK manager tool using the following command inside the folder where android-sdk-tools are located.

```
./sdkmanager
```

It gives me the following error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli
```

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: which version of the tools pacakge are you using?

Comment: @Blundell - I downloaded the version from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
Version = 26.1.1